# How do I add a delay to this jQuery mouseover?

Tags: jquery, popup, tooltip, mouseover, onmouseover

I'm using [this jQuery](http://pastie.org/2756030) and I've trying to figure out how to add a delay to this mouseover event. It's way too fast and I need it to wait at least a second before it executes the event.

The script is for a jQuery tooltip pop-up.

I'm not very clued up on JavaScript and jQuery yet, but I'm learning.

Comment: Try using the [`setTimeout`](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/) function

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a plugin called hoverIntent, it was build exactly to help with your problem and is very customizable: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: This is actually exactly what I'm looking for. I just can't seem to find any instruction on how to use and implement it.

Comment: How will I add the hoverIntent to work with my script though?